# How does a C++ Pointer really Treat Character Array and Integer/other datatype arrays?

Tags: arrays, c++11, pointers, character

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char x[]{"GOD BLESS!"};
    char *ptr = x; 
//    char *ptr{&x[0]}; 
    cout<<endl<<"Value of ptr is: "<<ptr; // here entire char array "GOD BLESS!" is displayed
    cout<<endl<<"Displaying array directely: "<<x; // here entire char array "GOD BLESS!" is displayed
    cout<<endl<<"Value inside the address in ptr is: "<<*ptr;
    cout<<endl<<"=================================================================="<<endl;
    int y[5]{1,2,3,4,5};
    int *ptr2 = y; 
//    int *ptr2{&y[0]};
    cout<<endl<<"Value of ptr is: "<<ptr2;
    cout<<endl<<"Value inside the address in ptr is: "<<*ptr2;
    cout<<endl<<"=================================================================="<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If this question is duplicate please forgive and link me to right source. PLEASE READ QUESTION FROM BEGINNING TO END.Compiling above code will be helpful.
Here in case of character array when i print the pointer value or simply the character array name it self i get entire array value for example "GOD BLESS!" here. While for integer array when i print it's pointer or simply array name only the address of first element in array is displayed.
WHY C++ TREAT CHARACTER ARRAY AND INTEGER ARRAY SO DIFFERENTLY SINCE WITH POINTER IT'S MAKE SO CONFUSING..

Comment: That's the way the language is. Printing a string makes sense, printing an arbitrary array is a more complex task.

Comment: By convention dating back to the '70es, a `char*` pointer often represents a string of text, terminated by `\0` character. This convention is still in widespread use in C and C++. For that reason, there's an overload of `operator<<(const char*)` that prints the string pointed to by the `char*` pointer, and an overload `operator<<(void*)` that prints the numerical value (the memory address) of the pointer itself. If you want to print the address represented by `char*` pointer, you can do that with `cout<<(void*)ptr`